# how to make droppable recognise when the draggable leaves?

Tags: jquery, droppable

I try to make a drag and drop game where you need to order the draggables. you may change the position of once dropped draggable.

So for this I need 
1. the droppable recognise when draggable is dropped on it and be disabled
2. droppable recognise when the dropped draggable has left it and be droppable again.

I have this so far for the first part. the second I can't manage...

```
$(".boxSentence").each( function(){

$(this).droppable({

activeClass: "highlight",

drop: 
$(this).addClass("noBorder occupied");
$(this).droppable("disable");
numOccupied++;
}
});
```

I have tried "out", but it works the other way.

If someone has any ideas, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it would be a nice method.... but I think, I found the way.

I made some other object droppable (obj2) and when I drop the draggable from it's previous location (obj1) onto it, it triggers the activation of the obj2

```
$(".obj2").droppable({
drop: function(event,ui){
$(".obj1").droppable("enable");
numOccupied--;
}
});

....
$(".obj1").each(function(){

$(this).droppable({

drop: $(this).addClass("noBorder occupied");
$(this).droppable("disable");
numOccupied++;
)};
)};
```

IF there is a nicer way I'd be glad to hear the ideas!